# Visual navigation graph representation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Jetpack navigation component has a nice visual representation of `nav_graph.xml` file between fragments, however if we use navigation component for Jetpack Compose there is no support `nav_graph.xml` for composable functions. Then the question is how visually to see  the navigation graph between composable widgets and screens similarly what we can see
with `nav_graph.xml` in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a visual representation of the graph yet. This article also mentioned.

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/navigating-in-jetpack-compose-78c78d365c6a

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32938345)

Answer (score -1):

Visualization of composable functions in Jetpack Compose Navigation is not supported in Android Studio at the moment. However as a workaround you could use Jetpack Navigation library and preview your composable widgets inside of fragments.

---

**Workaround:**

To get preview working, we can use [Jetpack Navigation library](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#Set-up) (non-compose version) for handling navigation inside the app and previewing graphs. Therefore, we need to use our composable widgets inside of a `Fragment`.

Create `XML` resource for your `Fragment` with a root element being `ComposeView`:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/composeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:composableName="com.example.myapplication.HomeScreenKt.PreviewHome" />
```

In `tools:composableName` attribute specify full path to your annotated `@Preview` function.

Then create a `Fragment` for your composable widget ([how](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#compose-in-fragments)):

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = FragmentHomeBinding
        .inflate(inflater, container, false)
        .also { _binding = it }
        .root

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initComposeView()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun initComposeView() {
        with(binding.composeView) {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                HomeScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create graph `res/navigation/home_graph` and add your fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
</navigation>
```

Don't forget to specify `tools:layout` tag as it tells Android Studio to draw the preview of `XML` file.

Build project and you will see working preview of a composable function inside the navigation graph!
[image]